# 'Active' del menú de navegación de Bootstrap no cambia

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap, menú

Estoy usando Bootstrap 4.

Uso `class="active"` en mi navbar pero no cambia cuando hago click en los distintos items de mi menú.

Este es mi `header.jsp` con los archivos js/css/bootstrap:

```
<!-- Bootstrap -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/common.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- jQuery, Popper.js y Bootstrap JS -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Este es mi código `navbar`:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
      <!-- <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a> -->
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
        <div class="navbar-nav">
          <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="welcome/index.do"><spring:message code="master.page.inicio"/><span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="security/login.do"><spring:message code="master.page.noticias"/></a>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#"><spring:message code="master.page.documentacion"/></a>
        </div>
      </div>
</nav>
```

Y este el script para cambiar el 'active':

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(".nav .nav-link").on("click", function(){
           $(".nav").find(".active").removeClass("active");
           $(this).addClass("active");
        });
</script>
```

El script no tiene ningún efecto y no caigo en qué estoy haciendo mal.

**EDIT SOLUCIÓN:**

Además de tener en cuenta la solución planteada por **@alanfcm**, para que el 'active' persista en una opción del menú que redirija a otra vista, es necesario añadir un script con la ruta de la opción del menú en cuestión en la vista correspondiente, no en el header. Quedaría así para el 1er item:

`header.jsp`:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
      <!-- <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a> -->
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
        <div class="navbar-nav">
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="welcome/index.do"><spring:message code="master.page.inicio"/><span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="security/login.do"><spring:message code="master.page.noticias"/></a>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#"><spring:message code="master.page.documentacion"/></a>
        </div>
      </div>
</nav>
```

`index.jsp`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">         
    $(document).ready(function() {
          $('nav .nav-link .active').removeClass('active');
          $('a[href="' + 'welcome/index.do' + '"]').addClass('active'); 
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es tu selector de jQuery.  Estas buscando por `.nav` o sea la clase nav.  En su lugar tienes que buscar por el elemento nav.  Simplemente remueve el punto.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/common.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- jQuery, Popper.js y Bootstrap JS -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>    

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
      <!-- <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a> -->
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
        <div class="navbar-nav">
          <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="welcome/index.do">(current)</a>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="security/login.do">spring:message code="master.page.noticias"/</a>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">spring:message code="master.page.documentacion"/</a>
        </div>
      </div>
</nav>

<div>
    <a href="?language=en">en</a> | <a href="?language=es">es</a>
</div>  
<script type="text/javascript">
        $("nav .nav-link").on("click", function(){
           $("nav").find(".active").removeClass("active");
           $(this).addClass("active");
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Lo he cambiado pero sigue sin modificarse el 'active'

Comment: En mi ejemplo si funciona.  Si seleccionas la tercera opcion, veras que tiene la clase `active`, recuerda que si el link recarga la pagina, el html se vuelve a generar, por lo que la primera opcion va a volver a tener la clase `active`

Comment: He editado el post con la estructura completa que tengo en el header, porque no sé si es por tener algo dentro de un bloque que no debería, ya que no se me ocurre de que otra cosa podría ser

Comment: En tu codigo, cuando seleccionas la tercera opcion, te funciona?

Comment: No, cuando inspecciono el elemento el 'active' sigue en la primera opción

Comment: Ya edite mi respuesta, tienes que mover el script al final del `HTML`

Comment: Así sí funciona la tercera opción, aunque las que redirigen a otro jsp no, por lo que he añadido un script en cada uno de los jsp distintos con la ruta determinada para solventar el problema. Gracias!